# In PostgreSQL, how to select the previous row value to compute the current row value?

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a PostgreSQL query where I want to compute the current row value based on the previous row value. Below is the table for example, the value1 column will have the first initial value and then I need to compute the rows after using the previous row value.

The formula for value1 column in the current row would be `previous value1 + the current row's id`.

Table:

[image]

Desired output :

[image]

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: This can probably not be done in a query.  You need to loop throught the records and save each one before proceding to calculate the next one.  You can calculate one row easily but not the whole table in one query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it.  It's not especially efficient though, but for a one off it should do.

```
select x.id, sum(coalesce(y.value1,y.id,0))
from sample x
left outer join sample y on x.id >= y.id
group by x.id
order by x.id
```

Basically, it goes through every record in the table, and then sums up the IDs of all the records up to and including that record.    There is a special logic to handle the initial value you've got on id=1.

SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8f25/1

Another option is to use a window function.

```
select x.id, sum(coalesce(x.value1,x.id,0)) over (order by x.id)
from sample x
```

SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b8f25/2

Comment: windows function worked perfectly fine, which I was looking for

Comment: this scenario works if I have to sum the id to value1,what if I have to multiply id to value1?

Comment: @user679530  for more complex maths, the recursive query posted by @klin offers full control of the formula.   Change the `p.value1+ t.id` part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive prev_row as (
    select id, value1
    from my_table
    where id = 1
union all
    select t.id, p.value1+ t.id
    from prev_row p
    join my_table t on t.id = p.id+ 1
)
select id, value1
from prev_row
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a8894a4a61c8af70d6446d19c54ab14f)